Расшифровка JavaScript
Недавно хотел посмотреть исходный код, и он оказался зашифрованным, как можно минимизировать или расшифровать код, сайты, программы есть что нибудь такое?
Отрывок кода:
function NcRwCzS() {}
var LlLxFc = Object['\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6e\x65\x50\x72\x6f\x70\x65\x72\x74\x79'],
    DGit40R, Fs8NIic, v6OU4S, ERibtG, kJmXEj, UV8NJjF, DBS1uKj, p4x9vg, oSKZYAW, tAjTkv, EVWClCv, MddeoLV, ZOoFZ0, xFr_5gf, thnA9m, PDKcZR, yq4LV4;

function bNB1iT(NcRwCzS) {
    return DGit40R[NcRwCzS < 0x132 ? NcRwCzS + 0x8 : NcRwCzS + 0x2a]
}
DGit40R = FNh7T6();

function sKPAx20(NcRwCzS, LlLxFc) {
    var v6OU4S = i5uIRe(NcRwCzS => {
        return DGit40R[NcRwCzS > 0xf8 ? NcRwCzS - 0x3f : NcRwCzS + 0x42]
    }, 0x1);
    Fs8NIic(NcRwCzS, v6OU4S(-0x42), {
        value: LlLxFc,
        configurable: v6OU4S(0x79)
    });
    return NcRwCzS
}
NcRwCzS(Fs8NIic = Object.defineProperty, v6OU4S = sKPAx20(i5uIRe((...LlLxFc) => {
    var Fs8NIic = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
        return DGit40R[LlLxFc < 0xe8 ? LlLxFc + 0x52 : LlLxFc - 0x12]
    }, 0x1);
    NcRwCzS(LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x8)] = Fs8NIic(-0x50), LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x7)] = LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x4)]);
    return LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(-0x51)](LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(-0x4f)]())
}), bNB1iT(-0x6))(VieZ7h0, nsiizkk));
var dkPui9 = [],
    arRUJF = ['\x4c\x66\x3b\x58\x2f\x5d\x7c\x75\x46', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(-0x5)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(-0x4)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(-0x6)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x4)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x5)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x3)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x11)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x16)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x1b)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x32)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x3d)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x5d)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x14)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x38)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x39)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x63)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x64)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x67)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x17)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x7c)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(-0x3)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x7e)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x86)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x1f)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x88)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x7a)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x89)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x1e)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x8a)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x2f)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(-0x3)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x8b)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x10)), '\x7b\x61\x74\x62\x31\x66\x7c\x24\x5e\x67\x3b\x5b\x25\x22\x77\x34\x72\x35\x25\x62\x6f\x6c\x4e\x5b\x44\x46\x3d\x6d\x4a\x4e\x2e\x5d\x7b\x46\x65\x62\x51', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x22)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x0)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x1)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x23)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xe)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x3c)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x8f)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x90)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x80)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x52)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x68)), bNB1iT(0x2), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x20)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x55)), bNB1iT(-0x2), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(-0x1)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x50)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x56)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x58)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x4f)), bNB1iT(-0x2), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(-0x1)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x5b)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x13)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x0)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x1)), '\u0064\u0076\u007c\u0040\u0078\u0064\u0023\u0033', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x5a)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x9e)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x28)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x9f)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xa1)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x96)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x82)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x95)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x29)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x83)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xe2)), bNB1iT(0x2), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x12)), bNB1iT(-0x2), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(-0x1)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x2a)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xe3)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xe4)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x81)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xe5)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xd8)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xe6)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x92)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xe7)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x84)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xf2)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xb6)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xf3)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xd1)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xb9)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xef)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xcc)), '\x7c\x3f\x58\x5a\x37\x56\x26\x74\x73', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xfc)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xe1)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(-0x7)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x46)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xdc)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x9a)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x27)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x49)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xb1)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x73)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x34)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x10a)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x4e)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x108)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x2b)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x109)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x70)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x5c)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x18)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x59)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x10c)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x10e)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x6a)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x111)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xb2)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x114)), '\u0037\u0024\u007c\u0032\u004b\u0061\u0047\u007e', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x94)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x115)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x116)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x99)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x117)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x6c)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x98)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x118)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x37)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x119)), '\x6e\x67\x47\x63\x35\x70\x73\x5a\x40\x47\x44\x44\x43\x3f\x7e\x52\x21\x3f\x6b\x79\x4c\x37\x72\x4e\x4a\x28\x65\x7c\x41\x2b\x5d\x53\x53\x3c\x4c\x69\x72', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xcf)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xb5)), '\u006f\u0056\u0071\u0074\u0035\u0060\u006b\u007c\u0056\u0052\u006b\u0077\u002e\u0056\u006f\u004a\u0062\u003c\u0035\u0037\u0030\u0036\u0049\u0047\u005f\u006a\u006f\u004f\u0077\u005b', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x11a)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xa5)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x11b)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x11d)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x11f)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xc)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x1d)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x120)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xd)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xa)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x45)), '\u0033\u0047\u005d\u004e\u006c\u0044\u0066\u0053\u0061\u0028\u007a\u005a\u0046\u003f\u0050\u0069\u005e\u0028\u0060\u007c\u0048\u0062\u0076', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xa9)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xdd)), KzxF8N(0x84), KzxF8N(0x85), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x54)), '\u0071\u0062\u007b\u0065\u0028\u0032\u006a\u007e\u0022\u005d\u0035\u006e\u0072\u007b\u007a\u005f\u0073\u006c\u0038\u0074\u0034\u0068\u0034\u0051\u005f\u004e\u0052\u0039\u0051\u0050\u004a\u0046\u0062\u0034\u0053\u0070\u0065\u004a\u0021\u007c\u0059\u0024\u0032\u0066\u0063\u0061\u006a', KzxF8N(0x87), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x51)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x106)), '\u006f\u0056\u002e\u006f\u006e\u0028\u006d\u003e\u0059\u0078\u0052\u0036\u0021\u002e\u0031\u0052\u0024\u003c\u003e\u007c\u0036\u0034\u0037\u007e', KzxF8N(0x8a), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xa2)), '\u0072\u0031\u0059\u0032\u0066\u0039\u007c\u007c\u0033\u006e\u0076\u0059\u002a\u0075\u0079\u0042\u007b\u0024\u0052\u0074\u0051\u0067\u0033\u0054\u0035\u0052\u0077\u0070\u0041\u0077\u0063\u0042\u0041\u006e\u0045\u007c\u0056\u0061\u0067\u007a\u004a\u0024\u0029', '\x7d\x5b\x66\x24\x5e\x3a\x66\x3c\x51\x48\x42\x3d\x34\x75\x24\x25\x6c\x34\x37\x24\x72\x7c\x52\x26\x73\x3f\x67\x4a\x22', '\u0031\u0073\u0049\u0059\u006d\u0029\u005d\u0052\u0071\u006a\u006b\u0050\u0032\u0028\u006c\u004c\u0021\u006a\u0042\u0053\u0079\u004f\u007c\u0051\u0071\u003d\u0074\u0039\u006b\u005b\u0051\u0078', '\u005a\u0031\u007c\u0043\u0069\u003f\u006f\u005a\u0054\u003f\u0049\u005e\u0026\u003f\u004d\u004c\u006b\u0037\u0023\u0074\u003f\u0044\u0026\u007e', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x113)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xac)), '\x45\x3f\x7d\x7c\x3f\x25\x68\x79\x34\x4e', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xc5)), KzxF8N(0x8f), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x3e)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x40)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x110)), '\x7a\x24\x5d\x59\x7e\x68\x49\x47\x7c\x37\x45\x22\x25\x54\x4c\x25\x6d\x67\x36\x7c\x37\x68\x74\x52\x47\x5e\x74\x6a\x2e\x3a\x47\x38', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x41)), '\x4c\x34\x60\x2e\x62\x25\x6c\x6f\x32\x34\x74\x6e\x50\x55\x52\x3d\x4b\x42\x45\x7c\x28\x59\x3b\x22\x62\x52\x65\x3f\x56\x2c\x22\x46\x4d\x71\x76\x60\x7c\x54\x52\x26\x5a\x4e\x75', '\u0043\u0073\u007c\u003e\u0046\u004b\u0038\u004b\u0069\u006e\u0049\u0026\u0023\u006a\u0076\u005f\u0026\u0037\u0070\u0039\u006c\u0044\u006b\u0052\u0023\u0066\u0072\u003d\u002b\u005b', KzxF8N(0x94), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x43)), '\u0025\u0024\u0043\u007c\u005f\u004b\u0054\u0054\u0059\u0024\u0060\u0056\u005b\u0038\u0054\u004c\u0028\u003f\u0022\u0074\u002a\u0067\u0045\u007c\u0079\u005e\u0075\u0057\u0072\u0029\u002e\u0052\u0062\u006d\u0058\u004e\u0042', KzxF8N(0x96), '\u0037\u0037\u0044\u0030\u0036\u006c\u0022\u0048\u0055\u0024\u0044\u004b\u0062\u003f\u0047\u0025\u002b\u003c\u002a\u007c\u0035\u007c\u0028\u0053\u002e', KzxF8N(0x97), KzxF8N(0x98), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x5f)), KzxF8N(0x9a), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xfa)), KzxF8N(0x9c), KzxF8N(0x9d), KzxF8N(0x9e), '\u006c\u005e\u0079\u004e\u0075\u004b\u0069\u004c\u0032\u004e\u0070\u0070\u003b\u006a\u006c\u0049\u004c\u0059\u0055\u0029\u006f\u007d\u003b\u004c\u0035\u005d\u007b\u0059\u004b\u005b\u007d\u006b\u0067\u006d\u0072\u007c\u0038\u003a\u004f\u0047\u006a\u0062\u005a\u0057\u002a\u0050\u0056', KzxF8N(0x9f), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xc3)), KzxF8N(0xa1), KzxF8N(0xa2), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xf)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x42)), KzxF8N(0xa5), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x11e)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xc2)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x9b)), KzxF8N(0xa9), '\x7d\x59\x45\x70\x7c\x54\x2b\x51\x5a\x5d\x6e\x4b\x76', '\u0039\u0049\u003e\u004f\u0069\u004a\u003d\u0026\u0058\u0024\u0052\u006e\u0077\u003a\u006a\u003c\u0047\u0031\u006e\u007a\u0024\u0077\u005d\u004b\u006a\u0052\u004a\u0057\u003e\u0056\u0073\u002a\u0059\u0031\u0075\u007c\u0031\u0029\u0038\u007c\u0066\u005e\u0045\u0061\u006d\u006a\u004e', '\u006f\u0037\u004a\u0039\u0026\u005a\u0064\u0051\u007d\u0040\u0035\u0026\u007d\u0046\u005d\u0052\u006e\u0034\u007c\u0063\u005d\u0028\u0029\u003c\u0028\u006e\u0049', '\u0030\u0067\u0075\u007c\u004a\u003c\u0059\u004c\u0059\u0037\u0052\u0077\u006c\u0028\u0053\u005e\u007b\u0056\u0046\u006f\u0066\u0039\u0065\u005a\u007a\u0078', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x72)), '\u006c\u0031\u0038\u0069\u002a\u0070\u006e\u004c\u0036\u0047\u0051\u0030\u005e\u0039\u0029\u006b\u0025\u0031\u0023\u0029\u002e\u0068\u002a\u0052\u0025\u0054\u0038\u0057\u0057\u0070\u0055\u0068\u002b\u0037\u0048\u007c\u0029\u0066\u0034\u007e', KzxF8N(0xab), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x47)), KzxF8N(0xad), KzxF8N(0xae), KzxF8N(0xaf), KzxF8N(0xb0), '\x2b\x52\x63\x69\x42\x5a\x52\x40\x74\x47\x42\x34\x24\x55\x4c\x65\x34\x67\x41\x43\x62\x25\x66\x52\x5e\x62\x79\x4b\x74\x39\x21\x4a\x73\x34\x7c\x43\x26', '\x21\x6e\x2e\x32\x44\x43\x70\x50\x29\x28\x66\x4a\x50\x28\x73\x25\x59\x68\x2a\x7c\x46\x4a\x5a\x3e\x23\x3d\x63\x37\x61\x46\x42\x6f\x6d\x6c\x7d\x65\x73\x2f\x4b\x45\x6b\x34\x56\x69\x22', KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x127)), KzxF8N(0xb2), '\u0042\u005f\u0041\u0079\u0026\u007c\u0021\u003c\u0032\u003f\u004c\u004a\u004b\u0056\u0047\u0078\u0063\u003c\u0035\u0037\u0044\u0043\u004f\u003c\u004f\u0048\u0058\u003f\u005d\u0075\u0064\u002b\u0040\u007a\u006b\u0063', KzxF8N(0xb3), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xb)), '\u007c\u006e\u002e\u0029\u002c\u0035\u0028\u0053\u0079\u005e\u002a\u005d\u003a\u007e\u006c\u006b\u0036\u0030\u0051\u0043\u007e\u0068\u0070\u0078\u0077\u0028\u007e\u0059\u007b\u002b\u005d\u0065\u003c\u006c\u003d\u003e', KzxF8N(0xb5), KzxF8N(0xb6), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0xc4)), KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x85)), '\x33\x38\x33\x79\x66\x36\x44\x53\x29\x24\x7e\x7e\x54\x42\x51\x38\x3f\x67\x77\x70\x6a\x4f\x5f\x6c\x7c\x24\x4e\x67\x23\x3a\x2b\x3d\x78\x37\x21\x24\x7c\x62\x76'];
ERibtG = sKPAx20((...LlLxFc) => {
    var Fs8NIic = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
        return DGit40R[LlLxFc > 0x137 ? LlLxFc - 0x23 : LlLxFc < -0x4 ? LlLxFc - 0xb : LlLxFc + 0x3]
    }, 0x1);
    NcRwCzS(LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x8)] = Fs8NIic(0x8), LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x7)] = LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x6)]);
    if (typeof LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x9)] === KzxF8N(Fs8NIic(0xb))) {
        var v6OU4S = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
            return DGit40R[LlLxFc < 0xdd ? LlLxFc > 0xdd ? LlLxFc + 0x53 : LlLxFc > 0xdd ? LlLxFc + 0x2f : LlLxFc > -0x5e ? LlLxFc + 0x5d : LlLxFc + 0x3d : LlLxFc + 0x50]
        }, 0x1);
        LlLxFc[v6OU4S(-0x51)] = _dL0oUi
    }
    if (typeof LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x5)] === KzxF8N(Fs8NIic(0xb))) {
        var kJmXEj = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
            return DGit40R[LlLxFc < 0x189 ? LlLxFc - 0x4f : LlLxFc - 0x16]
        }, 0x1);
        LlLxFc[kJmXEj(0x5c)] = dkPui9
    }
    if (LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x5)] !== LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x1)]) {
        var UV8NJjF = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
            return DGit40R[LlLxFc > 0x35 ? LlLxFc > 0x35 ? LlLxFc < 0x35 ? LlLxFc + 0x1d : LlLxFc > 0x35 ? LlLxFc - 0x36 : LlLxFc + 0x2 : LlLxFc - 0x9 : LlLxFc - 0x51]
        }, 0x1);
        return LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x5)][LlLxFc[UV8NJjF(0x39)]] || (LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x5)][LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x5)]] = LlLxFc[UV8NJjF(0x42)](arRUJF[LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x0)]]))
    }
    if (LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x9)] === ERibtG) {
        _dL0oUi = LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x1)];
        return _dL0oUi(LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0xc)])
    }
    LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x8)] = LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x5)];
    if (LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x1)]) {
        var DBS1uKj = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
            return DGit40R[LlLxFc < -0x21 ? LlLxFc - 0x4c : LlLxFc < -0x21 ? LlLxFc - 0x53 : LlLxFc + 0x20]
        }, 0x1);
        [LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x5)], LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x1)]] = [LlLxFc[DBS1uKj(-0x14)](LlLxFc[DBS1uKj(-0x13)]), LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0xd)] || LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x7)]];
        return ERibtG(LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x8)], LlLxFc[DBS1uKj(-0x13)], LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0xc)])
    }
    if (LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0xc)] == LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x9)]) {
        var p4x9vg = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
            return DGit40R[LlLxFc > 0x50 ? LlLxFc - 0x51 : LlLxFc - 0x2f]
        }, 0x1);
        return LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x4)] ? LlLxFc[p4x9vg(0x61)][LlLxFc[p4x9vg(0x5e)][LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x1)]]] : dkPui9[LlLxFc[p4x9vg(0x61)]] || (LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0xc)] = LlLxFc[p4x9vg(0x5e)][LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x8)]] || LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0x9)], dkPui9[LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x8)]] = LlLxFc[p4x9vg(0x60)](arRUJF[LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0xd)]]))
    }
    if (LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x4)] === Fs8NIic(0x29)) {
        ERibtG = LlLxFc[Fs8NIic(0xa)]
    }
    if (LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x7)] == LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x8)]) {
        var oSKZYAW = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
            return DGit40R[LlLxFc < 0x17 ? LlLxFc - 0x4c : LlLxFc > 0x152 ? LlLxFc - 0x7 : LlLxFc < 0x152 ? LlLxFc < 0x152 ? LlLxFc - 0x18 : LlLxFc - 0x40 : LlLxFc - 0x39]
        }, 0x1);
        return LlLxFc[oSKZYAW(0x1c)][dkPui9[LlLxFc[bNB1iT(0x7)]]] = ERibtG(LlLxFc[oSKZYAW(0x28)], LlLxFc[bNB1iT(-0x4)])
    }
}, bNB1iT(0x3));

function _kGYN8d() {
    return globalThis
}

function dYR43FZ() {
    return global
}

function d5FnJL() {
    return window
}

function bZJhKd9() {
    return new Function(KzxF8N(0xba))()
}

function WmhbxX(LlLxFc = [_kGYN8d, dYR43FZ, d5FnJL, bZJhKd9], Fs8NIic, v6OU4S = [], ERibtG, kJmXEj) {
    Fs8NIic = Fs8NIic;
    try {
        var UV8NJjF = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
            return DGit40R[LlLxFc > 0x39 ? LlLxFc < 0x174 ? LlLxFc < 0x174 ? LlLxFc - 0x3a : LlLxFc - 0x11 : LlLxFc + 0x46 : LlLxFc + 0x5f]
        }, 0x1);
        NcRwCzS(Fs8NIic = Object, v6OU4S[KzxF8N(UV8NJjF(0x5b))]('' [KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x1c))][KzxF8N(UV8NJjF(0xb6))][KzxF8N(0xbe)]))
    } catch (e) {}
    WM3juI6: for (ERibtG = bNB1iT(-0x5); ERibtG < LlLxFc[KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x9))]; ERibtG++) try {
        Fs8NIic = LlLxFc[ERibtG]();
        for (kJmXEj = bNB1iT(-0x5); kJmXEj < v6OU4S[KzxF8N(bNB1iT(0x9))]; kJmXEj++) {
            var DBS1uKj = i5uIRe(LlLxFc => {
                return DGit40R[LlLxFc > 0x182 ? LlLxFc + 0x6 : LlLxFc < 0x182 ? LlLxFc > 0x182 ? LlLxFc - 0xb : LlLxFc < 0x47 ? LlLxFc - 0x47 : LlLxFc - 0x48 : LlLxFc + 0x4c]
            }, 0x1);
            if (typeof Fs8NIic[v6OU4S[kJmXEj]] === KzxF8N(DBS1uKj(0x56))) {
                continue WM3juI6
            }
        }
        return Fs8NIic
    } catch (e) {}
    return Fs8NIic || this
}


достаточно простого find&replace в текстовом редакторе

См. Eng SO: De-obfuscate Javascript code to make it readable again (2012) P.S. Убрал метку Java
